# TeXstudio reading font information as error

Tags: errors, texstudio, newtx

The following mwe compiles with an overfull bad box, but somehow TeXstudio parses the log file as containing an error, I think confused by the either the `¹` or `º` in the relevant portion of the log file. Is this a bug in TeXstudio or is there actually an error?

In the second case, how do I fix it? Also why is the minimal example so complicated? I verified that the 'error' goes away if any of the packages or symbols in the equation are taken out (or if the textwidth is increased to 51mm or higher).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=50mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\cdots\to A_A(A,A;\mathscr{A}')\to A(A;A)A(
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

TeXstudio reads the following part of the log as an error:

```
\OML/ntxmi/m/it/10 A\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/10 �\OML/ntxmi/m/it/10 A\OT1/ntxtlf/m/n/10
Overfull \hbox (2.75075pt too wide) detected
```